# How to show a QDialog on a custom Windows Desktop (HDESK)

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, desktop-application

**Solution**

After several tests and good leads from the community, I can now confirm that it is mandatory to apply `SetThreadDesktop` **before** creating the `QApplication`. This is the only way to allow Qt to display QWidgets in the new desktop.

However, `SwitchDesktop` can be called before or after the QApplication, it doesn't matter as long as `SetThreadDesktop` has been called before the creation of the QApplication.

Thanks to all of you! I hope this topic will be useful for other people.

**Problem**

I'm working on a Qt project on Windows where i need to create a custom desktop (*HDESK*) using API such as [CreateDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdesktopa), [OpenDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-opendesktopa) and [SwitchDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-switchdesktop). On this new Desktop, i need to show a QDialog (using *exec* or *show* depending on my needs) but the QDialog is not displayed on the new desktop but on the "default" one.

My code looks something like this :

```
/* Starting the QApplication from the main function */
QApplication qApp;
qApp.exec();
/* [...] An HEVENT is fired or a Win32 COM call is made telling me than i need to display the QDialog */
/* Creating the new desktop and switching to it */
HDESK hNewDesktop=NULL;

hNewDesktop=CreateDesktop(L"_MyNewDesktopName", NULL, NULL, DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);

/* Creating the QDialog and showing it */
QDialog *pqdlgMyDialog=NULL;

pqdlgMyDialog=new QDialog(NULL);
pqdlgMyDialog.show(); // or .exec() depending on the my needs
```

Doing this, create and display a new desktop with a black background but the QDialog is displayed on the default desktop (the one we see when we start Windows).

I have to tried to set a parent to my QDialog doing something like this but it does not work either :

```
QWindow *pqwParentWindow=NULL;
QWidget *pwqParentWidget=NULL;
HWND hwndParentWindow=NULL;

hwndParentWindow=GetTopWindow(NULL); // I have also tried GetDesktopWindow, FindWindowEx etc.
pqwParentWindow=QWindow::fromWinId((WId)hwndParentWindow);
pwqParentWidget=QWidget::createWindowContainer(pqwParentWindow);
[...]
QDialog *pqdlgMyDialog=NULL;
pqdlgMyDialog=new QDialog(pwqParentWidget);
pqdlgMyDialog.show(); // or .exec() depending on the my needs
```

If someone has an idea, i'm willing to try everything !
I have done a lot of reading of Qt Documentation and MSDN, looking for stuff such as "Is a QApplication linked to a desktop" but without success...

Comment: After creating the new desktop, try calling `SetThreadDesktop()` before creating the dialog. `SwitchDesktop()` only makes the new desktop visible, it does not associate it with the calling thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but nothing changes unfortunately (i have tried 3 things : 1/ Replacing `SwitchDesktop` by `SetThreadDesktop`, 2/ Calling `SetThreadDesktop` after `SwitchDesktop` , 3/ Calling `SetThreadDesktop` before `SwitchDesktop`).

However, you make me realize something : my code which creates and show the desktop is called from a different thread than the one creating the QDialog (which is the gui thread as requiered by Qt). I'm possibly doing something wrong...

Comment: I've tried to call `CreateDesktop` and `SwitchDesktop` (or `SetThreadDesktop`) from the gui thread but that does not change anything either ^^

I keep digging....

Comment: Per the [`SetThreadDesktop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddesktop) documentation: "*The SetThreadDesktop function will fail if **the calling thread has any windows** or hooks on its current desktop (unless the hDesktop parameter is a handle to the current desktop)*". So using it from the main GUI thread will not work if your GUI is already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HWNDs are tied to threads and threads with HWNDs are tied to desktops.

> The SetThreadDesktop function will fail if the calling thread has any windows or hooks on its current desktop (unless the hDesktop parameter is a handle to the current desktop).

I don't know if QApplication creates a hidden window or if you have another HWND there but it is easy to demonstrate that `SetThreadDesktop` will fail if there is already a window on the thread:

```
HDESK g_hNew;

DWORD CALLBACK TrySwitch(LPVOID Param)
{
    if (Param)
    {
        CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"Existing window", WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (SetThreadDesktop(g_hNew))
    {
        SwitchDesktop(g_hNew);
        CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"New window", WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    Sleep(3333);
    return 0;
}

void Example()
{
    HDESK hIn = OpenInputDesktop(DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, false, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);
    g_hNew = CreateDesktop(L"_MyNewDesktopName", NULL, NULL, DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(CreateThread(NULL, 0, TrySwitch, (void*) TRUE, 0, NULL), 3333); // Leaks thread handle and I don't care
    WaitForSingleObject(CreateThread(NULL, 0, TrySwitch, (void*) FALSE, 0, NULL), 3333); // Leaks thread handle and I don't care
    SwitchDesktop(hIn);
    CloseDesktop(hIn);
    CloseDesktop(g_hNew);
}
```

Comment: You were right, `QApplication` must probably create an `HWND` somehow because calling `SetThreadDesktop` before creating the `QApplication` solves my problem. Thanks!